# Java endless Input Dialog loop

Tags: java

I'm making a GUI with some textfields and a submit button.
    I'm trying to verify the input so it doesn't change any values when the button gets pressed unless the values verify the condition, but it keeps looping regardless of the values I give it.

At first I wanted to do it with regular Message Dialogs but I can't change the input because the window is in the way and if I press OK the execution goes on anyway, so that's how i got to input dialogs. So yeah, I'd really appreciate some help here :)

```
int landPrice = ((int) (Math.random() * (26 - 17)) + 17);
int purchasedLand=0;

while (!inputAccepted) {
    purchasedLand = Integer.parseInt(landBox.getText().trim());
    if ((g.getGrain() - (purchasedLand * landPrice)) < 0)
        purchasedLand = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(landBox, 
                    "please re-input the amount of purchased land,"
                  + " we cannot afford the given amount! "));
    else {
        System.out.println("yay");
        inputAccepted = true;
    }
}
```

`g.getGrain()` is supposed to return 2800 at the start.

Comment: Once you're in the loop, there is no possibility for the user to update the state of the field (they're effectively locked out)

Comment: alright, so how else could I go about it without overcomplicating myself?

Comment: It's difficult to know, because I don't know how you got yourself into this hole. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MuadDib: can you please indent your code properly next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from this line:

```
purchasedLand = Integer.parseInt(landBox.getText().trim());
```

Although you update the variable within the `JOptionPane`, you always set it back to `landBox.getText().trim()`, so you never reach the `else` statement.

Final solution

```
int landPrice = ((int) (Math.random() * (26 - 17)) + 17);
int purchasedLand =Integer.parseInt(landBox.getText().trim());

while (!inputAccepted) {

    if ((g.getGrain() - (purchasedLand * landPrice)) < 0)
        purchasedLand = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(landBox, 
                    "please re-input the amount of purchased land,"
                  + " we cannot afford the given amount! "));
    else {
        System.out.println("yay");
        inputAccepted = true;
    }
}
```